# How format array in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I'm working in a matlab script that open a group of text files and read their content. The content is XY double points, separated by " ". I save the readed values in a Array like this:

```
    dataArray= textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'MultipleDelimsAsOne', true, 'EmptyValue' ,NaN, 'ReturnOnError', false);
```

This work fine but problems appear when i open multiple files because put the data in a array od data. Here the code and example:

```
for i = 1:length(files) 
    %% Open the text file.
    fileID = fopen([path files{i}],'r');
        dataArray = cat(1, dataArray, textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'MultipleDelimsAsOne', true, 'EmptyValue' ,NaN, 'ReturnOnError', false));
    end

    %% Close the text file.
    fclose(fileID);
end
```

The result of this is:

[image]

Where each cell is

[image]

I want that all values appear continuous like in the second picture. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you upload a small working example (with files)? It actually looks as if you're doing everything correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Cat should work, but for your example `[dataArray; textscan(...)]` looks even more convenient to me. Check first, whether what you load via textscan really has the format that you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that at your example image you have different data types. Column 1 and 2 are of type double and 3 is of type cell. To concentrate all in one variable it is necessary that everything is of type double. Check your `formatSpec` variable.

Also, your example code is not working because of an additional `end`.